# Select the next item in a listbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, listbox

I'm trying to loop through a listbox, selecting the next item every loop. But whenever I run the application it doesn't go to the next item, it just uses the first selected item.

```
lb.SelectedIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++)
{
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        string tn = lb.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string url = "https://enterprisecenter.verizon.com/enterprisesolutions/global/dlink/repairs/iRepair/DelegateDispatch.do?exec=delegateRoute&action=VIEW_BY_NUMBER_VIEW_TKT_SECTION&ticketNumber=" + tn + "&state=";
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = url;
        process.Start();
    }
    if (lb.SelectedIndex < lb.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        lb.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex + 1;
    } 
}
```

Edit: Removed Convert.ToInt32

Edit 2: Edited code to reflect changes

Edit 3: Correct Code

Comment: this: `Convert.ToInt32(lb.Items.Count.ToString())` should be simply `lb.Items.Count`

Comment: What this does `Convert.ToInt32(lb.Items.Count.ToString())`? I guess you like strings..

Comment: That might have done it. I don't know why I did that... Hm...

Comment: In case it isn't clear, your `Convert` call is wrong. You're converting an integer (`Count`) to a string using `ToString()` only to immediately use `Convert.ToInt32` to convert it back to an integer, which is totally unnecessary - just use `Items.Count` directly and cut out all of the noise and wasted CPU cycles.

Comment: Also `if (countMinusOne.ToString() == lb.SelectedIndex.ToString())` can be simply written as `if (countMinusOne == lb.SelectedIndex)`

Comment: Yeah I understand what I did wrong. I changed it and it still doesn't solve the issue, but it does make it cleaner and a bit less redundant.

Comment: the logic just doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. You need to modify the URL inside your loop, not above it:

```
lb.SelectedIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++)
{
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        string tn = lb.SelectedItem;
        string url = "privateURL" + tn + "privateURL";
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = url;
        process.Start();
    }
    lb.SelectedIndex := lb.SelectedIndex + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It has been a long coffee-less day.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

for the previous item:

```
if (lb.SelectedIndex > 0)
{ 
 lb.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex - 1; 
}
```

next item:

```
if (lb.SelectedIndex < lb.Items.Count - 1)
{
 lb.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex + 1;
}
```

If you need in detail you could refer this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92fdb8e2-47c9-49a0-8063-8533b78f41d0/c-listbox-select-nextprevious?forum=csharpgeneral

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't select the next item.